# How to translate "Through adventure to the stars" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Per ardua ad astra.  This is the well known RAF motto,  usually translated as "Through adversity to the stars".  I would like to keep the similarity to that motto, but have it mean, "Through adventure to the stars".  I can't find a word that seems appropriate for adventure in this sense.  Any ideas?  Thanks :)

Comment: I thought the original saying was *per aspera ad astra*?

Answer (score 6):

I would translate it:

*Per ausa ad astra.*

It's hard to capture the modern sense of the word *[adventure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adventure)* because we often associate with it experiences which are exciting or remarkable. However, I think the word *[ausa](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=ausus&la=la)* (from the the perfect passive participle of *audeo*) comes close because it means things risked or ventured, as well as carrying with it the idea of boldness or daring.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ausus#Latin) has the following:

> **Participle**
>  **ausus** m (feminine ausa, neuter ausum); first/second
>   declension
>
> dared, having dared, ventured, having ventured, risked, having risked
>   (poetic) having been eager for battle

Comment: Thank you, Expedito Bipes! That does sound like the right sort of meaning.  I was also wondering about "audacia", for a similar sense. Although perhaps "audacity" has a less positive flavour.

Comment: @Amelia. It's similar in meaning, but I think *ausa* shifts the focus away from the adventurers and more onto their undertakings.